# analytics: finding who contacted me

Tags: google-analytics

I have a contact form on one of my website's page and I would like to get statistics out of Google Analytics on people who actually used that contact form.

I could check the exit page (/contact) but that does not mean they used the form.

Is there a way to do that ? I would like to find out more about these people (where they came from, etc...) since they are my potential clients.

Comment: You can get all data at your email when user fill form and click on submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do they go when a form is successfully completed?
Normally you would take them to a thankyou page. You would then track this page to know who submitted the form.

Comment: good idea, but unfortunately it's not the case. It's an AJAX form that displays a thank you message on the same page.

Comment: Ok. I've not done any AJAX form submissions but this stackoverflow question may help you. It utilises event tracking. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14840350/1740835

Comment: great link  !  it works now :)